# Does $S_6$ have an abelian sylow $2$ subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

How do I check if $S_6$ has an abelian sylow 2 subgroup. Order of any sylow 2 subgroup is $16$ and by sylows theorem it has $45$ sylow 2-subgroups, but how to check whether it has any abelian sylow 2-subgroup or not?

Comment: Well, if one is abelian then they are all abelian, since they are conjugate to each other, hence isomorphic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$S_6$ contains various subgroups isomorphic to $S_4$, for example, the subgroup of permutations that permute $\{1,2,3,4\}$ but leave $5$ and $6$ fixed.

In turn, $S_4$ has subgroups isomorphic to $D_4$, the dihedral group of order $8$, where $\{1,2,3,4\}$ are viewed as vertices of a square.

Now, each copy of $D_4$ has order $8$, so it is a $2$-subgroup, and therefore it must be contained in a $2$-Sylow subgroup. Since $D_4$ is not abelian, neither is the $2$-Sylow subgroup.

Since all $2$-Sylow subgroups are conjugate, they are isomorphic, so this means that there are no abelian $2$-Sylow subgroups.

---

With a bit of extra work, we can construct a $2$-Sylow subgroup.

As noted above, $S_6$ contains copies of $D_4$ which permute only $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Call one of these copies $H$. Now define $K = \langle (56) \rangle$, which has order $2$. Since the elements of $H$ and $K$ commute, we have $HK = KH$, so $HK$ is a subgroup, and $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $HK$. Since we also have $H \cap K = 1$, we see that $HK$ is a direct product. Its order is
$$|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|} = \frac{8 \cdot 2}{1} = 16$$
and therefore $HK$ is the desired $2$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: This seems like a somewhat complicated way to do this. You have identified a non-abelian $2$-subgroup and hence the group cannot have an abelian $2$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Very good point, since $D_4$ is a $2$-subgroup, it must be contained in a $2$-sylow subgroup, so we're done. Still, it seems nice to see exactly what the $2$-sylow subgroup looks like, so I'll leave the answer as is.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft (Sorry, my previous comment was based on a misreading of your comment.) Yes, I guess you're saying the same thing as Morgan Rodgers - the copy of $D_4$ must be contained in a $2$-sylow  subgroup, end of proof.

Comment: Yes, precisely. I do agree that finding the precise structure of the Sylow subgroup is also a good idea.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for this observation. I think the edited answer is better as a result.